# How do I iterate zip list in jinja2 using for loop and display values in HTML table?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I was trying to iterate zip list in jinja2 and display values in HTML table but failed at every single try with a blank page, however, I can display values in the Unordered list like as follows.

```
<ul>
      {% for bus, info in jnjbus_info %}
       <li>{{bus}}</li>
       <li>{{info}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This is my flask/function where I passing values to template:

```
@app.route('/busses')
def busses():
    bus_type = ['AC', 'NON-AC', 'Sleeper', 'NON-Sleeper']   
    bus_info = ['1010', '2020', '3030', '4040']   
    return render_template('busses.html', jnjbus_info=zip(bus_type, bus_info))
```

I'm rendering template called busses.html
Here's the script:

```
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Bus Type</th>
            <th>Bus Information</th>
        </tr>
            {% for bus, info  in jnjbus_info %}
                <tr>    
                <td>{{bus}}</td>
                <td>{{info}}</td>               
               </tr>
           {% endfor %} 
    </table>
```

Comment: Move the loop around the `tr`s? You want to generate N many rows with two-columns - not one row with a large amount of columns next to each other, right? Also - you should put a thead and tbody in there...

Comment: I tried that as well no success.

Comment: please [edit] your question to show the latest code - have you also looked at your page source in the browser to see if there's anything that looks like something attempted to be output but somethings just not causing it to be displayed by stylesheets etc...?

Comment: Ok, I will edit the question, I have looked at the source as well there's nothing, whatever HTML tag I put inside a loop that will not display in the page source.

Comment: [here's_screen_shot_of_page_source](https://s26.postimg.org/gr6rahndl/Screenshot_from_2017-09-12_18_37_40.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code provided in this question is bug-free, however, the problem caused by `port=5000` and may be browser `cache` as well. While tackling with the bug I have written a similar script [py](https://pastebin.com/raw/Th7Q3bJg) and [html](https://pastebin.com/raw/7BkfTSqd) and [screen shot](https://s26.postimg.org/5p24vfa8p/Screenshot_from_2017-09-12_21_14_28.png) .and ran on `port=8888` which works like charm. *Note :* consider running the same application on different `ports` and clearing browser `cache`.

Answer (score 0):

**you don't have the**

```
<tbody> </tbody>
```

tag in your page i added it and it works:

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Bus Type</th>
        <th>Bus Information</th>
    </tr>
     <tbody>
    {% for bus, info  in jnjbus_info %}
        <tr>


            <td>{{bus}}</td>
            <td>{{info}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

here is how it looks like :

[image]

Comment: Then what's wrong with my side? [here's the screen shot of page source](https://s26.postimg.org/txw7a0j2x/Screenshot_from_2017-09-12_18_53_23.png)

Comment: I added  `<tbody></tbody>` as you suggested, please look at the screen shot in previous comment, mean time I'm gonna try it from scratch idk what's wrong going on.

Comment: your code looks also good it look like it is the matter view the browser: try to do an empty cache

Comment: please update your question with the full html that gives the output in picture ?

Comment: I have no idea what went wrong, I have written the similar script and ran on `port=8888` and it works like charm. This bug wasted my almost 6 hrs for a silly port reason. Here's clean working  code [py](https://pastebin.com/raw/Th7Q3bJg) and [html](https://pastebin.com/raw/7BkfTSqd) [screen shot](https://s26.postimg.org/5p24vfa8p/Screenshot_from_2017-09-12_21_14_28.png)