# Iterate Through Two Lists From JSON To HTML Table | Flask

Tags: python, html, json, list, html-table

The output, see how the character starts at the bottom when the other list ends:

[image]

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Cast</th>
    <th>Character</th>
  </tr>
    {% for cast in data[currentMovie]["cast"] %}
  <tr>
       <td>{{ cast }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for char in data[currentMovie]["character"] %}
      <td>{{ char }}</td>
 </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

What I would like to know is how to get it so its side by side, as right now the character starts at the end of the cast list. Any help is appreciated! The output is is shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping first "cast" and then "character". That is the issue.
you should loop both simultaneously like

```
for cast, char in zip(data[currentMovie]["cast"], data[currentMovie]["character"])
```

Comment: This was the right way about it but Jinja doesn't like Zip, I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176785/how-do-i-iterate-zip-list-in-jinja2-using-for-loop-and-display-values-in-html-ta Thanks For You Help! :)